# How to change font for the localization text inside *.arb file

Tags: android-studio, flutter

In Android Studio IDE, how can I change font for the localization text inside `*.arb` files:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You manage the font in the widget that uses that variable, not in the arb file.

Comment: @GrahamD Well, I intend to change the literal font in the `*.arb` file to make the text more readable for me as developer!

Comment: Well, I would presume that is a function of your editor / IDE rather than anything that the arb file type can accommodate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the `Fallback Font` inside `File>Settings>Editor>Font`. It was *not* set initially, so it was randomly choosing a hard-to-read font. After changing it to something like `Courier New`, now the text inside `*.arb` file is much more readable:

[image: Screenshot]